# C# How to get connection between two text files

Tags: c#, list, text-files

I have two text files readed into two different lists.

The 1st .txt contains ID and dog names, it looks like this:

[image: 1st.txt]

The 2nd .txt contains again the ID and the Type of the dog:

[image: 2nd.txt]

The question is: How can I write into console the names and the types of the same ID's?

The code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("dognames.txt", Encoding.Default);
        List<Names> Dog_names = new List<Names>();
        string header = Olvas.ReadLine();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            Dog_names.Add(new Names(Olvas.ReadLine()));
        }
        sr.Close();

        StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("dogtypes.txt", Encoding.Default);
        List<Types> Dog_types = new List<Types>();
        string header = Olvas.ReadLine();
        while (!sr2.EndOfStream)
        {
            Dog_types.Add(new Types(Olvas.ReadLine()));
        }
        sr2.Close();
    }
}
class Names
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;

    public Names(string DateLine)
    {
        string[] DateLineElements = DateLine.Split(';');
        this.ID = int.Parse(DateLineElements[0]);
        this.Name = DateLineElements[1];
    }
}
class Types
{
    public int ID;
    public string Dog_Type;

    public Types(string DateLine)
    {
        string[] DateLineElements = DateLine.Split(';');
        this.ID = int.Parse(DateLineElements[0]);
        this.Dog_Type = DateLineElements[1];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The classes should perhaps be called DogName and DogType - they shouldn't have plural names at least..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a linq join.. I'll use query syntax because I find it more readable for joins:

```
var j = from n in Dog_names
join t in Dog_types on n.ID = t.ID
select new {
  n.Name,
  t.Dog_Type
};

foreach(var d in j)
  Console.WriteLine($"Dog {d.Name} is a {d.Dog_Type}");
```

Plenty o tutorials out there for LINQ Join if you want to take a look at method syntax, e.g. [here](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/inner-join-in-linq/#:%7E:text=Using%20Linq%20Query%20Syntax%20to%20Perform%20Inner%20Join:,much%20similar%20to%20performing%20the%20join%20in%20SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<Names> names = new List<Names>();
    List<Types> types = new List<Types>();
    List<FinalItem> finalList = new List<FinalItem>();
    var listWithName = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
    foreach(var x in listWithName)
    {
        names.Add(new Names(x));
    }
    var listWithType = File.ReadAllLines("2.txt");      
    foreach(var x in listWithType)
    {
        types.Add(new Types(x));
    }
    
    finalList = names.Select(x=>new FinalItem{ID=x.ID,Name=x.Name, Dog_Type=types.FirstOrDefault(y=>y.ID==x.ID)});
    
}

class FinalItem
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Dog_Type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all you have complicated the really simple task.
There are multiple solutions for this.

This is one of possibility.

Create a model for this, like:

```
class Dog
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string DogType {get; set;} //it could be and even should be an enum
}
```

Next, just parse every line, for example:

```
class DogParser
{
  public Dog CreateDog(string line)
  {
      Dog dog = new Dog();
      string[] fields = line.Split(';');
      dog.Id = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
      dog.Name = fields[1];

      return dog;
  }

  public void UpdateDog(string line)
  {
    string[] fields = line.Split(';');
    int dogId = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
    Dog dog = SomehowGetDogById(dogId);
    dog.DogType = fields[0];
  }
}
```

Now, just read those files into different List objects. And iterate them. First, iterate dogs with names and use CreateDog method from DogParser. Save every dog in some list, or better Dictionary<int, Dog>, where key should be dog's id.

Then iterate the second list and in method `SomehowGetDogById` return dog from dictionary.

This solution is not complete and error prone. So you have to upgrade it to your needs.

As I said, this is only the step-by-step example. There are many solutions for this. The other would be to use some csv parser, for example you can read [this](https://programistka.com/przetwarzanie-plikow-csv-w-csharp-stalo-sie-przyjemniejsze-csvhelper/) and [this](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Join` LINQ method:

```
// Sample definitions
class Types { public int ID; public string Type; }
class Names { public int ID; public string Name; }
// Implementation
var types = new List<Types>();
var names = new List<Names>();
var joinedResults = names.Join(types, n => n.ID, t => t.ID, (name, type) => new { name.Name, type.Type });
```